# Using href to post PHP data?

Tags: php, get, href

I have some data that needs to be posted without the site's pre-defined style for forms getting in the way. Can I use an href to post data without the use of the form, and then retrieve it with PHP?

HTML Example:

```
<a href="rcon.php?action=roomForward&roomId=7" />
```

PHP Example:

```
<?php
[Function Stuff for roomForward Here..]
  $core->Mus('senduser', '$_GET["roomid"]', ' . USER_ID . ');
?>
```

My code isn't perfect but it's just supposed to make sense for now!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Putting parameters in the URL is a common thing to do, and accessing them with `$_GET` is commonplace. Are you asking about something different from that?

Comment: Well I was wondering if you can still retrieve the data from the URL as an alternative to using a form.

Comment: What else did you think URL parameters were for?

Comment: I didn't know if a form did that or what, but thank you.

Answer (score 5):

No, the href produces strictly `GET` requests.

You can *fake* it by having an onclick handler on a link that submits a form instead.

```
<script>
    function post(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("my_form").submit();
    }
</script>
<form action="action.php" method="post" id="my_form" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="val" />
</form>
<a href="#" onclick="post()">click me!</a>
```

Comment: That make's it a GET request not a POST request. Update this answer to explain the difference?

Comment: I think he's just using the word _post_ generically, to mean _submit_.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The whole point of allowing parameters in the URL is so that they can be retrieved by server scripts. They have nothing to do with forms, except that they can also be set by a form if it uses `method="get"`.